# Problem with Edit function overrides the local storage and throws errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

My edit function is overriding the local storage when I try to save and even messing with my delete function. not sure where is the issue. I tried finding the solution in similar posts but could not figure it out. GitHub repo for full code: https://github.com/ottowoolf/NotesApp.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Form, Container, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const Edit = ({ notes, setNotes }) => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    title: "",
    text: "",
    id: "",
  });
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    let index = notes.find((n) => n.id === id);
    let selectedNote = notes[index];
    console.log(notes[index]);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(selectedNote);
    setForm(selectedNote);
  }, [id, notes]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setForm({ ...form, [name]: value, id });
    console.log(form);
  };

  const saveNote = () => {
    if (form.title.trim() !== "" || form.text.trim() !== "") {
      setNotes((note) => {
        // return array - with the object of /id/ modified
        let index = note.find((n) => n.id === id);
        let newNotes = [...note];
        newNotes[index] = form;
        console.log(newNotes[index]);
        return newNotes[index];
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Container>
        <Form className='mt-3 w-50'>
          <Form.Group controlId='formBasicEmail'>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={form.title}
              name='title'
              type='text'
            />
          </Form.Group>

          <Form.Group controlId='formBasicPassword'>
            <Form.Control
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={form.text}
              name='text'
              as='textarea'
              cols='30'
              rows='10'
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form>
        <Button onClick={saveNote} className='btn btn-success'>
          Save
        </Button>
      </Container>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: your `Edit` component doesn't have a function to be called to set `localStorage`. How can it override `localStorage`?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea @SinanYaman I get and set items in a different component but once i click save, the data is deleted from local storage :(

Comment: No, what I was pointing out was this can't be happening. I skimmed through your code and found that inside Routes.jsx, you set the local storage. Problem is most likely there

Comment: I'll have a look at that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forked your GitHub repo and edited it using codesandbox

Here  is the link
https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dawn-bnv6v?file=/src/pages/Edit.js

Tell me if anything is missing.

Also, I'll suggest you clean up your code a bit. It looks a lot for a Notes App.

Comment: Thanks @abhishek very helpful mate. Definitely need to clean the code. Still noob and leqrning to refactor at the moment. Cheers mate

Comment: No Problem  @Otto , did the solution help?
And if you are a beginner then it's really great, all the best.

Comment: Yes, the solution worked  Thanks again!